# Ler dados do Excel com formatação correta em R ou Python

Tags: python, r

Estou trabalhando com dados da imagem e gostaria de ler apenas ao nível do município.

Os dados estão na hierarquia com maior indentação (Ex. Rondônia (Estado) -> Porto Velho (Microrregião) -> Buritis (Município)).

Os dados estão disponível no [link](https://biblioteca.ibge.gov.br/index.php/biblioteca-catalogo?view=detalhes&id=7135). Em especial, os dados da tabela apresentada corresponde à tabela tab703.xls do ano de 2010.

Existe alguma forma, preferencialmente em Python ou R, para fazer a leitura desses dados com a formatação correta?

Em uma das minhas tentativas, busquei transformar os dados de Excel (.xls) para CSV e a formatação não se manteve.

[image: Planilha]

Comment: Em Python, há a biblioteca [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Não é possível dar uma resposta adequada sem acesso ao arquivo. Pode indicar o link do IBGE? E talvez seja mais fácil baixar as tabelas já com o formato adequado em CSV pelo SIDRA: https://sidra.ibge.gov.br/pesquisa/registro-civil/tabelas. Pelo R, pode buscar e carregar as tabelas com o [pacote sidrar](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sidrar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução em duas etapas, usando R:

Primeiro, ler o arquivo desconsiderando as primeiras linhas e garantindo que a identação no nome das unidades territoriais será mantida.

```
library(readxl)

dados <- read_excel("tab703.xls",
          na = c("", "-"),  # considera como NA células vazias ou com "-"
          trim_ws = FALSE,  # preserva os espaços no começo e final das strings
          skip = 5)         # pula as 5 primeiras linhas

names(dados)[1] <- "municipio"
# nomeia a primeira coluna (sem nome por ter pulado as primeiras linhas)
```

Se vai atribuir novos nomes para as colunas, pode indica-los diretamente para `read_excel` com a opção `col_names`.

A etapa seguinte é selecionar as linhas correspondentes a municípios (6 espaços de identação) e limpar os espaços.

```
dados <- dados[grepl('^\\s{6}\\w', dados$municipio, perl = TRUE), ]
# seleciona as linhas que começam com 6 espaços seguidos por algum caractere alfanumérico:

dados$municipio <- sub('^\\s*', '', dados$municipio)
# remove os espaços antes do nome do município

dados
#> # A tibble: 5,528 x 12
#>    municipio  Total...2 `Entre cônjuges … Total...4 Consensuais `Não- consensua…
#>    <chr>          <dbl>             <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>
#>  1 Buritis          337               266        18          12                4
#>  2 Campo Nov…        23                21        NA          NA               NA
#>  3 Candeias …        80                62        NA          NA               NA
#>  4 Cujubim           57                47        NA          NA               NA
#>  5 Itapuã do…        87                71        NA          NA               NA
#>  6 Nova Mamo…        97                82        NA          NA               NA
#>  7 Porto Vel…      2932              2358       103          66               13
#>  8 Costa Mar…       178               142         2          NA                2
#>  9 Guajará-M…       161               116         8           5               NA
#> 10 São Franc…        10                 8        NA          NA               NA
#> # … with 5,518 more rows, and 6 more variables:
#> #   Não- consensuais requeridas pela mulher <dbl>,
#> #   Casais com filhos menores de idade <dbl>, Total...9 <dbl>, Diretos <dbl>,
#> #   Indireto <dbl>, Guarda dos filhos menores pela mulher <dbl>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Linguagem R

Sem dados é difícil dizer se o seguinte funciona.

O pacote `readxl` permite ler folhas do Excel com a região a ler no argumento `range`. Este argumeto precisa de um pacote adicional, o pacote `cellranger`.

Na foto parece que os dados dos municípios começam na linha 11, coluna 1. Estes valores são passados à função `cell_limits`.

```
library(readxl)
library(cellranger)

cell_limits(ul = c(11, 1))
#<cell_limits (11, 1) x (-, -)>

read_excel(ficheiro, range = cell_limits(ul = c(11, 1)))
```

Comment: De fato, os dados do município começam na linha 11, mas essa formação se repete para os demais estados, i.e, para o estado seguinte, existe a hierarquia sob endentação. Isso geraria algum problema?

Comment: @PedroHenrique O código da resposta vai ler tudo a partir da linha 11, coluna 1. Se vai haver problemas, talvez. Uma solução é ler tudo e depois filtrar só os municípios.

Comment: Membros da comunidade python: por favor, não deem voto negativo para respostas em R quando tanto as *tags* quando o corpo da pergunta indicam que a solução pode ser tanto em python quanto em R.